# How to calculate $\int_{-1}^{1}|x^n| dx ?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> I have to calculate $$\int_{-1}^{1}|x^n| dx$$

I don't know how to delete the absolute value.

Do I write $-x^n$ where $x$ from $-1$ to $0$ or write $(-1)^n x^n$ ?

Thank you

Comment: The not very practical integral of $|x^n|$ is $\frac x{n+1}  |x^n|$.

Answer (score 3):

You have $|(-x)^n|=|x^n|$ so $\int_{-1}^0 |x^n|dx = \int_0^1 |x^n|dx = \int_0^1 x^n dx$.

Here $|x^n|=x^n$ for $x\ge 0$ because $x^n\ge 0$.

Comment: please what is equal to $|x^n|$

Comment: I fixed the absolute value signs.

Comment: whene $x<0$  what is equal to |x^n|

Comment: for example |x|= x or -x , what is the definition for |x^n|

Comment: $|x^n|=x^n$ if $x^n\ge 0$ and $x^n=-x^n$ if $x^n<0$.

Answer (score 2):

The integrand is even, so the integral is $2\int_0^1 x^n dx=\frac{2}{n+1}$ for $n>-1$.

Comment: that's all? but if i want to delete the | | what i must write?

Comment: The modulus is an even function, so we can restrict the integration range, thereby simplifying the modulus to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to consider that $\;\left | x^{n} \right | = \left | x \right |^n$

Then, undo the absolute value as usual:
$$\left | x \right |=\left\{\begin{matrix}x,&  &x\geq0&\\ -x,& & x<0&\end{matrix}\right.$$

Use the additivity of integration on intervals to compute:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\left | x^{n} \right |dx=\int_{-1}^{0}(-1)^nx^ndx\;+\;\int_{0}^{1}x^ndx,\quad \forall n>0\qquad \left(1\right)$$

Be careful!

For $n<0\,$ the function is not bounded. It is a simple example of improper integral.

However, for $\,-1<n<0\,$ the improper integral converges so you can be sure that $\,\left(1\right)\,$ is true $\,\forall n > -1.$

The particular case $\,n=0\,$ has no mathematical interest cause $\,\left|x\right|^n=1\,$ if $\,x\neq0\,$ and $\,\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\,\left|x\right|^x = 1.$